# Trouble choosing canonical question (Java printf variable field width)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical

Today I found this question when going through some tags:

- [Formatted Output With Variable Spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367384/formatted-output-with-variable-spacing)

I was sure this must have been asked before, and wanted to find a canonical question I could link, so I looked and the best I found was this:

- [Java printf using variable field size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550123/java-printf-using-variable-field-size)

However, that question has a weird problem for my purposes here: It is almost an XY problem, where Y is the part I'm interested in, the top answer (the one I'm interested in, which actually wasn't posted until 3 years later) addresses Y, but the accepted answer addresses X.

I think this makes it unsuitable for the canonical question. The first example above, though, actually could work well, even though it is much more recent.

So my question is, what is the best action to take:

1. Use the second example as the canonical (doesn't feel right).
2. Use the first example as the canonical and mark the second one as a duplicate (but this ignores the "X" in the XY problem).
3. Use the first example as the canonical and leave the second one untouched.
4. Post a new self-answered question to use (doesn't seem right, the first example is clear).
5. Something else.

I am leaning towards #3, even though it might mean marking some older questions as a duplicate of a newer one (which always makes me feel funny inside).